# Is the return type of a function part of the mangled name?

Tags: c++, name-mangling

Suppose I have two functions with the same parameter types and name (not in the same program):

```
std::string foo(int x) {
  return "hello"; 
}

int foo(int x) {
  return x;
}
```

Will they have the same mangled name once compiled?

Is the the return type part of the mangled name in C++?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It's up to the compiler.

Comment: Darwin sorts this out.  Compilers that allow a completely wrong function to be linked or produce an (almost) undiagnosable linker error do not get used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mangling schemes aren't standardised, there's no single answer to this question; the closest thing to an actual answer would be to look at mangled names generated by the most common mangling schemes.  To my knowledge, those are the GCC and MSVC schemes, in alphabetical order, so...

---

### GCC:

To test this, we can use a simple program.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string foo(int x) { return "hello"; }
//int         foo(int x) { return x; }

int main() {
    // Assuming executable file named "a.out".
    system("nm a.out");
}
```

Compile and run with GCC or Clang, and it'll list the symbols it contains.  Depending on which of the functions is uncommented, the results will be:

```
// GCC:
// ----

std::string foo(int x) { return "hello"; } // _Z3fooB5cxx11i
                                             // foo[abi:cxx11](int)
int         foo(int x) { return x; }       // _Z3fooi
                                             // foo(int)

// Clang:
// ------

std::string foo(int x) { return "hello"; } // _Z3fooi
                                             // foo(int)
int         foo(int x) { return x; }       // _Z3fooi
                                             // foo(int)
```

The GCC scheme contains relatively little information, not including return types:

- Symbol type: `_Z` for "function".
- Name: `3foo` for `::foo`.
- Parameters: `i` for `int`.

Despite this, however, they are different when compiled with GCC (but not with Clang), because GCC indicates that the `std::string` version uses the `cxx11` ABI.

Note that it does still keep track of the return type, and make sure signatures match; it just doesn't use the function's mangled name to do so.

---

### MSVC:

To test this, we can use a simple program, as above.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
    
std::string foo(int x) { return "hello"; }
//int         foo(int x) { return x; }
    
int main() {
    // Assuming object file named "a.obj".
    // Pipe to file, because there are a lot of symbols when <string> is included.
    system("dumpbin/symbols a.obj > a.txt");
}
```

Compile and run with Visual Studio, and `a.txt` will list the symbols it contains.  Depending on which of the functions is uncommented, the results will be:

```
std::string foo(int x) { return "hello"; }
  // ?foo@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z
  // class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl foo(int)
int         foo(int x) { return x; }
  // ?foo@@YAHH@Z
  // int __cdecl foo(int)
```

The MSVC scheme contains the entire declaration, including things that weren't explicitly specified:

- Name: `foo@` for `::foo`, followed by `@` to terminate.
- Symbol type: Everything after the name-terminating `@`.
- Type and member status: `Y` for "non-member function".
- Calling convention: `A` for `__cdecl`.
- Return type:

  - `H` for `int`.
  - `?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@` (followed by `@` to terminate) for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>` (`std::string` for short).
- Parameter list: `H` for `int` (followed by `@` to terminate).
- Exception specifier: `Z` for `throw(...)`; this one is omitted from demangled names unless it's something else, probably because MSVC just ignores it anyway.

This allows it to whine at you if declarations aren't identical across every compilation unit.

---

Generally, most compilers will use one of those schemes (or sometimes a variation thereof) when targeting *nix or Windows, respectively, but this isn't guaranteed.  For example...

- Clang, to my knowledge, will use the GCC scheme for *nix, or the MSVC scheme for Windows.
- Intel C++ uses the GCC scheme for Linux and Mac, and the MSVC scheme (with a few minor variations) for Windows.
- The Borland and Watcom compilers have their own schemes.
- The Symantec and Digital Mars compilers generally use the MSVC scheme, with a few small changes.
- Older versions of GCC, and a lot of UNIX tools, use a modified version of cfront's mangling scheme.
- And so on...

<sup>Schemes used by other compilers are thanks to [Agner Fog's PDF](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).</sup>

---

### Note:

Examining the generated symbols, it becomes apparent that GCC's mangling scheme doesn't provide the same level of protection against Machiavelli as MSVC's.  Consider the following:

```
// foo.cpp
#include <string>

// Simple wrapper class, to avoid encoding `cxx11 ABI` into the GCC name.
class MyString {
    std::string data;

  public:
    MyString(const char* const d) : data(d) {}

    operator std::string() { return data; }
};

// Evil.
MyString foo(int i) { return "hello"; }

// -----

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

// Evil.
int foo(int);

int main() {
    std::cout << foo(3) << '\n';
}
```

If we compile each source file separately, then attempt to link the object files together...

- GCC: `MyString`, due to not being part of the `cxx11` ABI, causes `MyString foo(int)` to be mangled as `_Z3fooi`, just like `int foo(int)`.  This allows the object files to be linked, and an executable is produced.  Attempting to run it causes a segfault.
- MSVC: The linker will look for `?foo@@YAHH@Z`; as we instead supplied `?foo@@YA?AVMyString@@H@Z`, linking will fail.

Considering this, a mangling scheme that includes the return type is safer, even though functions can't be overloaded solely on differences in return type.

Comment: However, even on Itanium, the return type is part of the mangled name of a function **if it was instantiated from a template**. This is what made it safe to change the return type of `emplace_back` in C++17: https://wg21.link/P0084

Answer (score 1):

No, and I expect that their mangled name will be the same with all modern compilers. More importantly, using them in the same program results in undefined behavior. Functions in C++ cannot differ only in their return type.

Comment: Factually incorrect on 2 counts.  1) Visual Studio mangled names contain the entity's full type; those functions are `?foo@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z` and `?foo@@YAHH@Z`, respectively.  Similarly, GCC mangled names also contain some type information, although not as much as MSVC names; those functions are `_Z3fooB5cxx11i` and `_Z3fooi`, respectively (return type isn't preserved, but the `std::string` one identifies that it uses the `cxx11` ABI).  (They may be identical on some versions of GCC.)

Comment: 2) There is no reason to assume that all compilers use the same mangling scheme; it is entirely possible (and somewhat probable) that each compiler will use their own.  For example, Visual Studio and GCC both have their own mangling schemes, with a good number of other compilers using their schemes as unofficial "standards" for Windows and *nix, respectively.  The Borland and Watcom compilers also have their own unique schemes, and older versions of GCC (along with a lot of UNIX tools) use a modified version of cfront's mangling scheme.

Comment: The Intel compiler generally uses the MSVC scheme for Windows, and the modern GCC scheme for *nix.  Symantec and Digital Mars generally use the MSVC scheme, with a few small changes.  And so on.  See [here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf), it's kinda interesting.

Comment: To my knowledge, none of them will actually _compile_ the code as is, but if each function is compiled individually, their names aren't guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: (They _will_ be identical if compiled by Clang on Linux, though, for example, even though it uses the GCC scheme.  It varies from compiler to compiler.)

Comment: I agree with you, based on the fact that the return type must be unique. Mangling the return type would add extra safety, anyway, in the unlikely case that separate compilation units define such conficting functions without them ever being declared in the same unit.