# Clang compiles different function signatures into same symbol

Tags: c++, clang++

I was going through a c++ linker tutorial and playing with some function calls when I hit upon something that I assumed would give me a linker error, but did not.

I am compiling on MacOS using LLVM version 10

```
❯ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I have 2 cpp files, `log.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

void Log(const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

and `math.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int Log(const char* message);

int Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    int res = Log("Multiply");
    std::cout << "Got res: " << res << std::endl;
    return a * b;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Multiply(5, 8) << std::endl;
}
```

In `math.cpp` I am intentionally declaring the `Log` function with a mismatched return type. I expected this to compile but then fail to link but in fact it links just fine. I even saved off the return value and print it for funsies and it's garbage as expected because the `Log` function doesn't return anything.

```
/tmp
❯ c++ math.cpp log.cpp -o math

/tmp
❯ ./math
Multiply
Got res: -2002196896
40
```

I went further by dumping the assembly and looking at the function symbol being generated:

```
/tmp
❯ c++ -S math.cpp log.cpp

/tmp
❯ ls -l *.s
-rw-r--r-- 1 rsahae wheel 31924 Jun  9 11:38 log.s
-rw-r--r-- 1 rsahae wheel 32022 Jun  9 11:38 math.s

/tmp
❯ grep Log log.s math.s
log.s:  .globl  __Z3LogPKc              ## -- Begin function _Z3LogPKc
log.s:__Z3LogPKc:                             ## @_Z3LogPKc
math.s: callq   __Z3LogPKc
```

So now I understand why the linker doesn't give an error, because the symbols appear to be the same, even though the method signatures are different.

I looked around a bit on the internet but I couldn't find a post explicitly telling me why this behavior is happening.

I tried other variations of return types (float and string) which still generated the same symbol. I also tried changing the arguments which obviously do produce a different symbol and therefore error as expected.

Can anyone help explain or point me to the documentation as to why the compiler is compiling these two declarations with different signatures (of return type) into the same symbol?

Comment: As any book on C++ should tell you, the return type is not part of the function signature. You can't overload on return type. Mismatching declaration and definition of functions leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Different C++ compilers are *not* required to implement the same ABI (part of which is name mangling). This is why you should always compile *all* of your code with the same compiler. And the return type has never been part of the ABI - you cannot overload on it.

Comment: Ok understood. I should have further clarified that I tried a windows compiler and it did give a linking error, which was a contributor to the source of my confusion. I did a couple searches on return type and method signatures and now I see what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the return type part of the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/290038/608639), [Is the return type of a function part of the mangled name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40791413/608639), etc.

Comment: You can also use `c++filt` to demangle: `$ echo __Z3LogPKc | c++filt` results in `Log(char const*)`.